# What are the various "vimdiff" difftools/mergetools?

Tags: git, vimdiff, mergetool

When I run `git difftool --tool-help` or `git mergetool --tool-help`, I see:

- `vimdiff`
- `vimdiff1`
- `vimdiff2`
- `vimdiff3`

What are these different "versions"? I assume they all start Vim with different options, but what are the options? Are they documented anywhere?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They don't seem to be documented anywhere, unfortunately.

The relevant source code is [here](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.32.0/mergetools/vimdiff). Note how `vimdiff`, `nvimdiff`, and `gvimdiff` are all implemented with the same script.

### Difftool

When invoked as a difftool, they all do the same thing:

```sh
vim -R -f -d \
  -c 'wincmd l' \
  -c 'cd $GIT_PREFIX' \
  "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
```

This starts Vim in read-only mode `-R` and diff mode `-d`. For information on diff mode, see the manpage `vimdiff(1)` and the Vim help page `diff.txt`.

### Mergetool

When invoked as a mergetool, the behavior of these options varies.

In the diagrams below, `Local` corresponds to "ours", `Remote` corresponds to "theirs", `Base` corresponds to "merge base", and `Merge` is the file that will actually be saved to the work tree (and staged to the index if the resolution is successful).

#### `vimdiff`

If there is a "merge base" present, the window layout is:

```sh
# | Local | Base | Remote |
# | --------------------- |
# |        Merge          |

vim -f -d \
  -c '4wincmd w | wincmd J' \
  "$LOCAL" "$BASE" "$REMOTE" "$MERGED"
```

If there is not a merge base present, the layout is:

```sh
# |       |       |        |
# | Local | Merge | Remote |
# |       |       |        |

vim -f -d \
  -c 'wincmd l' \
  "$LOCAL" "$MERGED" "$REMOTE"
```

#### `vimdiff1`

The layout is:

```sh
# |       |        |
# | Local | Remote |
# |       |        |

vim -f -d "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
ret="$?"
if test "$ret" -eq 0
then
  cp -- "$LOCAL" "$MERGED"
fi
```

`Local` will then be saved to the work tree upon success, taking the place of `Merged`.

#### `vimdiff2`

The layout is identical to `vimdiff` without a merge base.

#### `vimdiff3`

Each of `Local`, `Remote`, `Base` (if present) will be opened but hidden. `Merged` will be opened and visible. You can switch among these buffers with the `:buffer` command.

```sh
# With Base
vim -f -d \
  -c 'hid | hid | hid' \
  "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" "$BASE" "$MERGED"

# Without Base
vim -f -d \
  -c 'hid | hid' \
  "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" "$MERGED"
```

### Create your own mergetool!

Let's create a `vimdiff4`, which uses the same layout as `vimdiff`-with-Base, but omitting the Base part.

Add the following to your Git config (e.g. `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config`):

```
[mergetool "nvimdiff4"]
  # Like "nvimdiff", but always ignore $BASE.
  cmd = nvim -f -d -c '$wincmd w' -c 'wincmd J' $LOCAL $REMOTE $MERGED
```

When you invoke `git mergetool --tool-help`, you will see a new line in the output:

```
    user-defined:
        nvimdiff4.cmd nvim -d -c '$wincmd w' -c 'wincmd J' $LOCAL $REMOTE $MERGED
```

Now you can run `git mergetool --tool=nvimdiff4`, which will invoke the command we specified above.

Answer (score 1):

The [`Documentation/mergetools/vimdiff.txt`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/79f2338b3746d23454308648b2491e5beba4beff/Documentation/mergetools/vimdiff.txt) recently (2022) documented:

> In addition, for backwards compatibility with previous Git versions, you can also append `1`, `2` or `3` to either `vimdiff` or any of the variants (ex: `vimdiff3`, `nvimdiff1`, etc...) to use a predefined layout.
>
> In other words, using `--tool=[g,n,]vimdiffx` is the same as using
> `--tool=[g,n,]vimdiff` and setting configuration variable
> `mergetool.[g,n,]vimdiff.layout` to...
>
> - `x=1`: `"@LOCAL, REMOTE"`
> - `x=2`: `"LOCAL, MERGED, REMOTE"`
> - `x=3`: `"MERGED"`
>
> Example: using `--tool=gvimdiff2` will open `gvim` with three columns (`LOCAL`,`MERGED` and `REMOTE`).

---

This should work better with Git 2.37.3 (Q3 2022), which does fix a "`vimdiff3`" regression.

See [commit 34133d9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/34133d9658a079b15af97c7c11d22939719e302d), [commit b6014ee](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b6014eeac0963ccad3f769fc6cdd09a4a64f478d), [commit ffcc33f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ffcc33f6a6923ade435a65d6cba751b3b95e6fd8), [commit 60184ab](https://github.com/git/git/commit/60184ab4d3c7fa56a721236e53aa957226bd399f), [commit 66dd83a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/66dd83ad09bce1d4234f853a004c2d22d485fd84), [commit 79db50d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/79db50d82103dcf64cb379eb08074ebb5d66c2d1), [commit d619183](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d619183710718cbcb22b0d56956c033ce1f714bc) (10 Aug 2022) by [Felipe Contreras (`felipec`)](https://github.com/felipec).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 4d8074b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4d8074bf8eb7c1f9891cd70b4aeaa48203bfdf20), 18 Aug 2022)</sup>

> ### [`mergetools`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b6014eeac0963ccad3f769fc6cdd09a4a64f478d): vimdiff: fix single window layouts
>
> <sup>Cc: Fernando Ramos</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Felipe Contreras</sup>
> <sup>Reviewed-by: Fernando Ramos</sup>

> Layouts with a single window other than "`MERGED`" do not work (e.g. "`LOCAL`" or "`MERGED+LOCAL`").
>
> This is because as the documentation of `bufdo` says:
>
> ```
> The last buffer (or where an error occurred) becomes the current
> buffer.
> ```
>
> And we do always do `bufdo` the end.
>
> Additionally, we do it only once, when it should be per tab.
>
> Fix this by doing it once per tab right after it's created and before any buffer is switched.